# int does not override Integer in Java

Tags: java

I had a function in Java with method signature

```
public void myMethod (int someInt, String someString)
```

in my abstract class and I had over-ridden it with method

```
public void myMethod (Integer someInt, String someString)
```

The over ride does not work. Is this an inconsistency ? I thought auto-boxing applied to method signature over-ride as well.

Comment: Perhaps you thought of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501412/why-does-autoboxing-make-some-calls-ambiguous-in-java

Comment: 'I had over-ridden it with method myMethod(Integer, String)'.

Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`int` and `Integer` are two different types. Autoboxing blurs the distinction at the source code level for the convenience of programmers, but does not change the fact that they are in fact two *very* different types.

As such, you can not `@Override` a method that takes an `int` with one that takes an `Integer` and vice versa.

Note that you should probably think twice before declaring a method to take an `Integer` instead of an `int`. Here's an excerpt from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 49: Prefer primitives to boxed primitives*:

> In summary, use primitives in preference to boxed primitive whenever you have the choice. Primitive types are simpler and faster. If you must use boxed primitives, be careful! Autoboxing reduces the verbosity, but not the danger, of using boxed primitives. When your program compares two boxed primitives with the `==` operator, it does an identity comparison, which is almost certainly not what you want. When your program does mixed-type computations involving boxed and unboxed primitives, it does unboxing, and when your program does unboxing, it can throw `NullPointerException`. Finally, when your program boxes primitive values, it can result in costly and unnecessary object creations.

There are places where you have no choice but to use boxed primitives, e.g. generics, but otherwise you should seriously consider if a decision to use boxed primitives is justified.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)
- [Is it guaranteed that new Integer(i) == i in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831945/is-it-guaranteed-that-new-integeri-i-in-java) (YES!!! The box is unboxed, not other way around!)
- [Why does `int num = Integer.getInteger("123")` throw `NullPointerException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception) (!!!)
- [Why null == 0 throws NullPointerException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-null-0-throws-nullpointerexception-in-java/)

Comment: +1: Very good answer, nailing not just this question but the other host of issues that cluster around it.

Comment: @Donal: well I've been known to go too far "off subject" on some answers, but I hope I hit just on target with this one. I was tempted to write about how subsignatures are specified for `@Override` purposes (JLS 8.4.2), but I managed to held back... this time...

Comment: I usually avoid prospective stuff unless it is either exactly relevant or the questioner has shown some expertise. The question, and at the level it was asked, is always my focus (except in comments; I'll witter on about irrelevant rubbish there. ;-))

Answer (score 4):

No, these two signatures define two different methods.

Answer (score 2):

They are absolutely not overridden but overload since the parameters are different. And JVM will choose the method to launch base on this:
widen - boxing - var args...

For example, you have three methods

```
void add(long n) {} // call this method 1
void add(int... n) {} // call this method 2
void add(Integer n) {} // call this method 3
```

and when you invoke:

```
int a = 5;
add(a);
```

the method 1 will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the override doesn't work is because `Integer`and `int` are two different things. `Integer` is an object, whereas `int` is a primitive type. Java does the implicit typecasting for you. For example:

`int myInteger = new Integer(5);`

Will create a primitive int type called `myInteger` with a value of 5. As the Javadoc says,

> "The `Integer` class wraps a value of
>   the primitive type `int` in an
>   object."

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this scenario will not work because Java provides the functionality of the autoboxing, so at runtime JVM can not decide which method to call because it can call both method as both method fits for the argument type. So I think it will give an error or will choose either method randomly..... Just run it and see.....

Answer (score 0):

int and Integer are two different types in JAVA.Although autoboxing specifies the distinction at the source code level, but does not change the eternal fact that they are in fact two very different types.